# ListBox Item limit on Delphi XE5 FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, livebindings

I´m using listbox component and LiveBindings to list the content of a field, but the table has 14443 records and the lisbox displays only 200 records. The version of delphi XE5 is a try license. What the limit lines of a listbox? The mobile is running Android.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show more than 200 rows in TStringGrid using LiveBindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591818/how-to-show-more-than-200-rows-in-tstringgrid-using-livebindings)

Answer (score 9):

The LiveBindings components that can hold multiple records like the `TCustomBindList`, `TCustomBindGridList`, `TCustomBindGridLink` and `TCustomLinkListControlToField` had a property called `BufferCount` with a default value of `-1`. When the internal db enumerator (`TBindScopeDBEnumerator`) of the LiveBindings  is initialized the value of this property (BufferCount) is checked and if his value is minor than 0, then a buffer of `200` elements is set. 
  So to overcome this limitation  you need to change the value of the `BufferCount` to a higher value or to the RecordCount value of your TDataSet.

Another alternative is set the `AutoBufferCount` property to true, which will set the internal `BufferCount` value to the number of records of the TDataSet.