# Do LiveBindings support a fetch-on-demand mechanism?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, livebindings

I want to replace a VCL TDbGrid with a FMX solution.

I choosed a `TListView` that is connected to the (`TQuery`-based) data via `TBindSourceDB` and `TBindingsList`. All connected via the Visual LiveBindings Designer (like in the MasterDetailTablet_Search example).

I want to display several thousand rows. But with the default settings only 200 records are displayed. If I [set AutoBufferCount to `True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591818) all records are displayed, but this is very slow. All data is loaded into memory.

Is there a mechanism in LiveBindings that allows to fetch the data on demand? (For instance, starting with 200 records in the buffer and filling more if needed.)

If not, any idea how I could start implementing such a feature? There is [not much documentation available](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.Bind.Components.TCustomLinkFillControlToField.OnFilledList) from Embarcadero.

Comment: TClientDataSets have always supported fetch-on-demand, via the PacketRecords property, fwiw.  Try experimenting  ...

Comment: @MartynA My `TQuery` descendant (`TIBOQuery`) does support fetch-on-demand (I used the same query with the original `TDbGrid`). But this does not help, if `TBindSourceDB`/`TListView` is fetching all the data. All I found, regarding this, seems to suggest, that with LiveBindings always all data is fetched.  But I am not sure on this one and I found no documentation.

Comment: I just did a test with a TDBGrid and a live-bound TListBox.  Connected only to the TDBGrid, my ClientDataSet certainly respects the PacketRecords setting, but with the TListBox bound, it retrieves all its provider-dataset's records.

Comment: @MartynA That's what I was trying to say. You found a better wording to describe the problem.

Comment: Sure, I was just confirming your observation.  If I manage to find a way around it, I'll be back.  Meanwhile +1 for an interesting q.